# After upgrading to TS 0.9 I get TS5007: Cannot resolve referenced file:, how do I fix this?

Tags: typescript

We recently upgraded to TS 0.9 and some of the TS files that were previously working fine no longer compile and we get:

> TS5007: Cannot resolve referenced file: ...

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I started off by taking 2 files from our source that I could work with in isolation.

One was a definition file (*.d.ts) and the other a normal file with implementations for the interfaces in the definition file. The definition file was giving the error described above.

I then began removing chunks of code from the definition file until the error went away and I was able to compile it.

This indicated to me that there was a problem in the comments in that file as the problem appeared/disappeared when I added/removed certain comments.

I started experimenting with the position and content of the comments and found that whether the comments were in-line or on their own line didn't make a difference. However comments with non-ASCII characters did cause the issue!

Armed with this information I went to the Typescript codeplex page to report the bug and found that someone already had.

[Cannot handle non-ASCII Unicode characters](https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/1173)

<s>So the solution, for now, is to not use Unicode characters within your code.</s>

So the solution for now, is to resave the file with Unicode encoding.

[TypeScript 0.9 - Could not find file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17194481/typescript-0-9-could-not-find-file/17195110#17195110)

Comment: The solution is to save your file in UTF-8 instead of ANSI, not to remove Unicode characters from the file.

Comment: That works too, thanks for the suggestion. Care to leave it as a proper answer rather than a comment so I can accept it? I guess the final solution there then is that the VS extension should make unicode encoded files to begin with?

Comment: You also could have linked through to your answer on the newer question about this problem.

Comment: A small tool called '[UTFCast](http://www.rotatingscrew.com/utfcast-express.aspx)' can help you with batch converting ANSI files to UTF-8.

Comment: It's amazing that it's 2013, and things like Compass/SASS and TypeScript still get tripped up over file encodings.

Comment: @ mdocter: Thank you very much! It certainly was much easier to bulk all our files than do it manually.

Comment: @ Nicholas: It's unfortunate, but typescript still is under development and so such things are to be expected. If it's still like this when it goes properly gold then I'll be amazed/saddened!

Comment: Excellent, thanks!  This was driving me crazy all day.  +1 across the board!

Answer (score 2):

I also ran into this issue, however it had nothing to do with encoding.

If you have too many files with the `TypeScriptCompile` Build Action in Visual Studio, and you are using a custom command line `Exec` in your csproj `BeforeBuild` or `AfterBuild`, you may see the same "cannot resolve referenced file" error.

If you have too many files, or a lot of files with relatively long paths (myproj/scripts/reallylongfoldername/reallylongilename.ts), they can't all fit into the command line arguments. Look carefully at the error. For me, simply adding a new `file.ts` to the project caused the error:

Cannot resolve referenced file: C:\Path\To\Project\scripts\file.s

That's not a typo above. The compiler actually removed the "t" from the "file.ts" in order to make it fit on the command line, and since the file "file.s" does not exist, I got the error.

The solution was to add a custom build target. I only ran into this problem after installing Visual Studio 2013, since it wants all of the definition files to have a TypeScriptCompile Build Action. So I just copied these 2 files into a Build folder under my solution:

**SolutionFolder\Build\Microsoft.TypeScript.Default.props**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TypeScriptRemoveComments>false</TypeScriptRemoveComments>
    <TypeScriptNoImplicitAny>false</TypeScriptNoImplicitAny>
    <TypeScriptNoResolve>false</TypeScriptNoResolve>
    <TypeScriptGeneratesDeclarations>false</TypeScriptGeneratesDeclarations>
    <TypeScriptModuleKind>amd</TypeScriptModuleKind>
    <TypeScriptOutFile></TypeScriptOutFile>
    <TypeScriptOutDir></TypeScriptOutDir>
    <TypeScriptSourceMap>true</TypeScriptSourceMap>
    <TypeScriptMapRoot></TypeScriptMapRoot>
    <TypeScriptSourceRoot></TypeScriptSourceRoot>
    <TypeScriptTarget>ES5</TypeScriptTarget>
    <TypeScriptAdditionalFlags></TypeScriptAdditionalFlags>
    <TypeScriptEnableCompileOnSave>true</TypeScriptEnableCompileOnSave>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

**SolutionFolder\Build\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets**

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <VsToolsPath Condition="'$(VsToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VsToolsPath>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <UsingTask TaskName="TypeScript.Tasks.VsTsc" AssemblyFile="$(VSToolsPath)\TypeScript\TypeScript.tasks.dll" />

  <PropertyGroup>
    <CompileDependsOn>
      CompileTypeScript;
      $(CompileDependsOn);
    </CompileDependsOn>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <PublishPipelineCollectFilesCore>
      $(PublishPipelineCollectFilesCore);
      TypeScriptCollectPublishFiles;
    </PublishPipelineCollectFilesCore>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(TypeScriptBuildConfigurations)' == ''">
    <TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled Condition="'$(TypeScriptEnableCompileOnSave)' != 'false'">true</TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>
    <PreferredUILang Condition="'$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)' == 'true' and '$(PreferredUILang)' == ''">$([System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::CurrentUICulture.Name)</PreferredUILang>

    <TypeScriptBuildConfigurations Condition="'$(TypeScriptRemoveComments)' == 'true'">$(TypeScriptBuildConfigurations) --removeComments</TypeScriptBuildConfigurations>
    <TypeScriptBuildConfigurations Condition="'$(TypeScriptNoImplicitAny)' == 'true'">$(TypeScriptBuildConfigurations) --noImplicitAny</TypeScriptBuildConfigurations>
    <TypeScriptBuildConfigurations Condition="'$(TypeScriptNoResolve)' == 'true'">$(TypeScriptBuildConfigurations) --noResolve</TypeScriptBuildConfigurations>
    <TypeScriptBuildConfigurations Condition="'$(TypeScriptGeneratesDeclarations)' == 'true'">$(TypeScriptBuildConfigurations) --declaration</TypeScriptBuildConfigurations>
    <TypeScriptBuildConfigurations Condition="'$(TypeScriptModuleKind)' != ''">$(TypeScriptBuildConfigurations) --module $(TypeScriptModuleKind)</TypeScriptBuildConfigurations>
    <TypeScriptBuildConfigurations Condition="'$(TypeScriptOutFile)' != ''">$(TypeScriptBuildConfigurations) --out &quot;$(TypeScriptOutFile)&quot;</TypeScriptBuildConfigurations>
    <TypeScriptBuildConfigurations Condition="'$(TypeScriptOutDir)' != ''">$(TypeScriptBuildConfigurations) --outDir &quot;$(TypeScriptOutDir)&quot;</TypeScriptBuildConfigurations>
    <TypeScriptBuildConfigurations Condition="'$(TypeScriptSourceMap)' == 'true'">$(TypeScriptBuildConfigurations) --sourcemap</TypeScriptBuildConfigurations>
    <TypeScriptBuildConfigurations Condition="'$(TypeScriptTarget)' != ''">$(TypeScriptBuildConfigurations) --target $(TypeScriptTarget)</TypeScriptBuildConfigurations>
    <TypeScriptBuildConfigurations Condition="'$(TypeScriptNoResolve)' == 'true'">$(TypeScriptBuildConfigurations) --noResolve</TypeScriptBuildConfigurations>
    <TypeScriptBuildConfigurations Condition="'$(TypeScriptAdditionalFlags)' != ''">$(TypeScriptBuildConfigurations) $(TypeScriptAdditionalFlags)</TypeScriptBuildConfigurations>
    <TypeScriptBuildConfigurations Condition="'$(TypeScriptMapRoot)' != ''">$(TypeScriptBuildConfigurations) --mapRoot &quot;$(TypeScriptMapRoot)&quot;</TypeScriptBuildConfigurations>
    <TypeScriptBuildConfigurations Condition="'$(TypeScriptSourceRoot)' != ''">$(TypeScriptBuildConfigurations) --sourceRoot &quot;$(TypeScriptSourceRoot)&quot;</TypeScriptBuildConfigurations>
    <TypeScriptBuildConfigurations Condition="'$(TypeScriptCodePage)' != ''">$(TypeScriptBuildConfigurations) --codepage $(TypeScriptCodePage)</TypeScriptBuildConfigurations>
    <TypeScriptBuildConfigurations Condition="'$(PreferredUILang)' != ''">$(TypeScriptBuildConfigurations) --locale $(PreferredUILang)</TypeScriptBuildConfigurations>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TscToolPath Condition="'$(TscToolPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript</TscToolPath>
    <TscToolExe Condition="'$(TscToolExe)' == ''">tsc.exe</TscToolExe>
    <TscYieldDuringToolExecution Condition="'$(TscYieldDuringToolExecution)' == ''">true</TscYieldDuringToolExecution>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PropertyPageSchema Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)\$(LangName)\TypeScriptProjectProperties.xaml;">
      <Context>Project;BrowseObject</Context>
    </PropertyPageSchema>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectCapability Include="TypeScript" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="CompileTypeScript" Condition="'$(BuildingProject)' != 'false'">
    <VsTsc
      ToolPath="$(TscToolPath)"
      ToolExe="$(TscToolExe)"
      Configurations="$(TypeScriptBuildConfigurations)"
      FullPathsToFiles="@(TypeScriptCompile)"
      YieldDuringToolExecution="$(TscYieldDuringToolExecution)"
      OutFile="$(TypeScriptOutFile)"
      OutDir="$(TypeScriptOutDir)"
      >
      <Output TaskParameter="GeneratedJavascript" ItemName="GeneratedJavascript" />
    </VsTsc>
  </Target>

  <Target Name="TypeScriptCollectPublishFiles">
    <Message Text="Adding to FilesForPackagingFromProject: @(GeneratedJavascript->'%(Identity)')"/>
    <ItemGroup>
      <FilesForPackagingFromProject Include="@(GeneratedJavascript->'%(Identity)')"/>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>

</Project>
```

I then modified the csproj file of the project that houses all of these typescript files. Put the following right before the `<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />` line (near the top of the file):

```
<Import Project="..\Build\Microsoft.TypeScript.Default.props" />
```

Then put the following right after the `<Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />` line (near the bottom of the file):

```
<Import Project="..\Build\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets" />
```

This will build typescript in both VS 2012 and 2013. You can also add a condition clause to each of the imports if have a special build configuration for building ts:

```
<Import Project="..\Build\Microsoft.TypeScript.Default.props" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'DebugBuildTs' Or '$(Configuration)' == 'Release'" />
<Import Project="..\Build\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'DebugBuildTs' Or '$(Configuration)' == 'Release'" />
```

Comment: Do you know if this still happens with TS v1.0? I'm getting - VSTSC : error TS5007: Build: Cannot resolve referenced file: 'COMPUTE_PATHS_ONLY'. [C:\a\src\Main\RecruitCloud\RecruitCloud.csproj]

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this issue.  This problem only appeared after I installed Visual Studio 2015 with Web Developer Tools, when I was previously using Visual Studio 2013 where everything was working fine.  It would now build and work in VS2015, but would throw up this error if I tried to build it on VS2013.  I ended up just moving my development to VS2015 instead.