# TypeScript 0.9 - Could not find file

Tags: typescript

Just upgraded to v0.9 and several files in my project fail to compile with

> error TS5004: Could not find file: 'myfile.ts'.

In an effort to troubleshoot one,
I compiled its dependencies individually trying to narrow down the issue, but they all compile fine. So, I'm back to this file. Web Essentials' background compilation isn't showing any errors. What might be causing this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's almost certainly because the file is saved with ANSI encoding and contains a non-ASCII character ('smart' quotes of the single or double variety are prime offenders here). The best solution is to save the file in UTF-8 encoding, though you could also just remove the ANSI characters to make the file all-ASCII again.

Comment: That's it. I re-saved the file in UTF-8 and it now compiles. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try removing the file and re-creating it? It might be as a result of how the file was originally added to the project .